# Algorithm to convert fiscal periods to calendar periods

Tags: objective-c, ios, algorithm, date, datetime

### What I am trying to do

I am somewhat desperately trying to build an algorithm which **converts financial figures from different companies from fiscal periods to calendar periods**.

### The problem

**Fiscal** periods often do not correspond to **calendar** periods, e.g. a company might report fiscal year 2011 revenues of 100 USD but its fiscal year does not end at the end of December 2011 but instead on September 2011. For instance, [Apple](http://investor.apple.com/faq.cfm?FaqSetID=3)'s fiscal year ends end of September. [Dell's](http://content.dell.com/us/en/corp/d/financials/investor-faqs) fiscal year ends end of January and [Intel](http://www.intel.com/intel/company/corp4.htm)'s fiscal year ends end of December. For Apple and Dell, all fiscal quarter and fiscal half year ends are shifted as well.

In order to compare revenues or other financial metrics among these companies, I need to be able to convert each fiscal period into equivalent calendar periods. For instance, someone might ask, how much revenue each company generated in calendar year 2011.

In the case of Apple Corp., we would need to remove the revenues which have been generated in calendar period 2010, which would equal Apple's fourth quarter of FY2010 and add the first quarter of fiscal year 2012 (which ended December 2011).

### What I have (data model)

My data model has the following attributes for each entity `calendarPeriod` and `fiscalPeriod`:

`endYear` (year in which the period ends)
`endMonth` (month number
   1..12 at which last day the period ends)
`length` (number of months 1..12 of the period)

### What I need (desperately)

What would be the most efficient and short algorithm I could accomplish this?

It would be great if the algorithm could handle "special situations" like Dell where it would need to take 1/3 of its fiscal first quarter, which ends *awfully* on January, of the following year and adding it to the last quarter of the preceding year. In addition the algorithm should be flexible enough to handle all period lengths and endMonths and try to combine periods if necessary (for instance for the first half of calendar year 2012, it should try to find a six month period which ends June 2012 or consecutively add two periods (one ending March 2012 and one ending June 2012 or taking a fiscal year which ends June 2012 and subtracting the quarters or half year which fall in calendar year 2011).

Thank you so much.

Comment: Even Apple's quarter contains 16 weeks, 3 extra weeks, sometimes 10weeks. So it would be very difficult to predict. For some project I had to ask EDW for the database containing fiscal week, month, quarter, year. And mind you it was horrible.

Comment: Please ignore these special cases. Let's just take quarters, half-years (6M periods) and fiscal years for simplicity, e.g. lengths of 3, 6 and 12 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a financial question then technical question.

If you have end of year results only, there is no practical way you could compare unless they are for same financial period.

Further, if you somehow manage to get the monthly results and do some juggling to prepare comparable results, they will not be comparable as there are many accounting adjustments and provisions generally done in the end of year financial result and not in monthly results which you will miss here.

I would suggest that you should try to compare those results which yields more meaningful results.

Comment: In addition to fiscal year end results, I have quarterly (sometimes only semi-annual) results. I know about the accounting adjustments and the general issues when comparing different companies and periods, but put these concerns aside: There must be a somewhat lightweight algorithm to add all fiscal periods which contain to a specific calendar period and subtract those which don't. I have done a lot of these calculations manually in Excel before and would like to automatize them now.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to obtain yearly results that way but it is hard to have a generic algo for it as each company have different kind of financial transactions which needs to be treated with proper discretion in order to yield comparable results. I had same issue but much less complicated, i.e. I had to compare only three companies but my conclusion was - it is possible to do so automatically but results will not be dependable.